# Use WithColumn with external function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have data in a DataFrame with below columns

1. Fileformat is csv
2. All below column datatypes are String

   employeeid,pexpense,cexpense

Now I need to create a new DataFrame which has new column called `expense`, which is calculated based on columns `pexpense`, `cexpense`.

The tricky part is the calculation algorithm is not an **UDF** function which I created, but it's an external function that needs to be imported from a Java library which takes primitive types as arguments - in this case `pexpense`, `cexpense` - to calculate the value required for new column.

The function signature which is from an external Java jar

```
public class MyJava

{

    public Double calculateExpense(Double pexpense, Double cexpense) {
       // calculation
    }

}
```

So how can I invoke that external function to create a new calculated column. Can I register that external function as UDF in my Spark application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your UDF of the external method similar to the following (illustrated using Scala REPL):

```
// From a Linux shell prompt:

vi MyJava.java
public class MyJava {
    public Double calculateExpense(Double pexpense, Double cexpense) {
        return pexpense + cexpense;
    }
}
:wq

javac MyJava.java
jar -cvf MyJava.jar MyJava.class

spark-shell --jars /path/to/jar/MyJava.jar

// From within the Spark shell

val df = Seq(
  ("1", "1.0", "2.0"), ("2", "3.0", "4.0")
).toDF("employeeid", "pexpense", "cexpense")

val myJava = new MyJava

val myJavaUdf = udf(
  myJava.calculateExpense _
)

val df2 = df.withColumn("totalexpense", myJavaUdf($"pexpense", $"cexpense") )

df2.show
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
|employeeid|pexpense|cexpense|totalexpense|
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
|         1|     1.0|     2.0|         3.0|
|         2|     3.0|     4.0|         7.0|
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: i was about to post the same thing but anyways thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply "wrap" the given method in a UDF by passing it as an argument to the `udf` function in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val myUdf = udf(calculateExpense _)
val newDF = df.withColumn("expense", myUdf($"pexpense", $"cexpense"))
```

This assumes `pexpense` and `cexpense` columns are both `Double`s.

Comment: As i mentioned calculateExpense is an external function which is part of a class named MyJava .i need to instantiate this class and invoke that with object reference ..Is your solution still valid ?

Comment: (was offline) - the answer is yes, you just have to instantiate a MyJava instance and use it to reference the method, as @leo-c showed in a similar answer...

Answer (score -1):

bellow, is an example of sum two columns:

```
val somme= udf((a: Int, b: int) => a+b)

val df_new = df.select(col("employeeid"), \
                       col("pexpense"),   \
                       col("pexpense"),   \
                       somme(col("pexpense"), col("pexpense")) as "expense")
```

Comment: the function is an external Java function not an UDF which i defined in my application